# Optimal Agent Allocation Strategy for Efficient Build

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a question regarding azure-pipeline configurations that I can't figure-out how to solve.

**Pipeline** - Automation, Fast, Slow
**Build** - An instance\single-run of the pipeline, on a specific commit
**Job** - The parts\steps of a build
**Task** - The parts\steps of a job
**Agent** - The server that runs the jobs

Every build starts with building the environment for the tests, an action that takes time.

I want to achieve -

1. Once a build has started on a specific agent, this agent won’t take any job from different builds, until the current build is complete. - Is there any way to do it?
2. The max number of agents on one build is 3
3. We prefer that the maximum amount of agents will be handling the same build at once
4. Every build can run on one agent or more

Currently the status is that the agents are jumping from one build to another, and leaving some builds un-handled.

My current YAML configuration's file -

```
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
    - 2.*

parameters:
  - name: 'tests'
    type: object
    default:
      - "test_1"
      - "test_2"
      - "test_3"
      - "test_4"
      - "test_5"
      - "test_6"
      - "test_7"
      - "test_8"
      - "test_9"

stages:
  - stage: RunTests
    displayName: 'Run Tests'
    jobs:
      - job: ui
        timeoutInMinutes: 120
        pool:
          name: Nightly
          demands:
            - Cmd
            - DotNetFramework

        strategy:
          maxParallel: 3
          matrix:
            ${{ each test_case in parameters.tests }}:
              ${{ test_case }}:
                test: ${{ test_case }}

        steps:
          - task: DeleteFiles@1
            displayName: 'Delete past session artifacts'
            inputs:
              sourceFolder: 'C:/dev'
              contents: |
                /files/**/*
                /temp/**/*
            condition: always()

          - task: DeleteFiles@1
            displayName: 'Delete past session captures'
            inputs:
              sourceFolder: 'C:/test_capture'
              contents: |
                **/*
            condition: always()

          - task: BatchScript@1
            displayName: 'configure z'
            inputs:
              filename: 'scripts\configure_z.bat'
              modifyEnvironment: false
            timeoutInMinutes: 20

          - template: build_env.yaml

          - task: BatchScript@1
            displayName: 'Run script automation/run_tests.bat '
            inputs:
              filename: 'automation/run_tests.bat'
              arguments: $(test)
              modifyEnvironment: false
            condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Canceled'))

          - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
            displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact'
            inputs:
              artifactName: Automation logs $(Agent.JobName) Attemp $(System.JobAttempt)
              targetPath: 'c:\test_capture'
            condition: always()

          - template: publish_test_results.yaml

  - stage: WrapUp
    displayName: 'Wrap Up'
    dependsOn: RunTests
    jobs:
      - job: PublishCompiledLogs
        displayName: 'Publish Compiled Logs'
        timeoutInMinutes: 20
        pool:
          name: Nightly
          demands:
            - Cmd
            - DotNetFramework

        steps:
          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
            inputs:
              patterns: '**/nosetest-*.xml'
              path: './tests-xml'
            condition: always()

          - task: CmdLine@1
            displayName: 'Combine Logs'
            inputs:
              filename: python
              arguments: 'scripts/merge_nosetest_logs.py --directory tests-xml --output tests-xml/nosetest-automation.xml --remove'
            continueOnError: true
            condition: always()

          - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
            displayName: 'Publish All Tests Artifact'
            inputs:
              artifactName: All Automatic Tests Logs
              targetPath: './tests-xml'
            condition: always()
```

Comment: Your steps are interdependent and sequential and so are your jobs. What parts do _you_ think can run parallel on different agents? You can't combine logs for a test that hasn't run yet... You could perhaps run test sets as separate jobs, but each agent will need to pull sources, restore and build (stuff you now have hidden in batch files).

Comment: *Every build starts with building the environment for the tests, an action that takes time.*. Can you build a container with your test prerequisites in it and then re-use a version of that container image?

Comment: I don't want to change anything in the build process.
I just want that if an agent has started working on "build A", It will execute all of the available build's jobs (test_1, test_2, test_3, etc..) until there are no jobs left on "build A", without moving on to the "build B" in the middle.